# Change colour in df.reset_index().plot bar plot

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I have the following code that produces the graph shown. How can I change the orange colour to red? I have tried saying c="red" but that turns both the orange and the blue bars red

`df.reset_index().plot(x="index", y=["Ic_tape_inner", "Ic_tape_outer"], kind="bar", figsize=(10,6))` 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the colors as a list e.g.  `color=["blue","red"]`

```
 (pd.DataFrame({"Ic_tape_inner":[10,12,13],"Ic_tape_outer":[1,2,3]})
  .reset_index().plot(x="index", y=["Ic_tape_inner", "Ic_tape_outer"],
   kind="bar", figsize=(10,6),color=["blue","red"])
 )
```

[image]